# Php is not logging into php_error

Tags: php, error-handling

For some reason that I don't know my php is not logging anything to the php_error.log file, I already changed to this settings, and restarted the server.

Any thoughts about what it could be the problem? (I got the following settings from phpinfo();)

```
Core

PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.23

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  Off Off
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   /var/log/php_errors.log /var/log/php_errors.log
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   22527
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  Off Off
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20090626  /usr/lib/php5/20090626
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors Off Off
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/PEAR    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/PEAR
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    Off Off
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    256M    256M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   150M    150M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 50M 50M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
```

UPDATE:

There's actually no php_errors.log after I restarted apache:

less /var/log/php_errors.log
/var/log/php_errors.log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd try removing the log file making apache create a new log file. If the prblem persists make sure all users are allowed to write to the file.

Comment: I didn't remove the file but I granted rwx to all users. So you mean remove the file and restart apache?

Comment: Yeah try restarting it, other than that i dont know what to do?